# How to decrease the font size / zoom out in Chrome on a mobile device

Tags: google-chrome, iphone

I prefer very small fonts: on my MacBook I use full retina *2560x1600*.  My `iPhone7 Plus` can show a lot - *if I can force chrome to stop making huge fonts on it*.  But how to do that?  The desktop chrome allows to decrease magnification by hitting `Command-Minus`. There is no keyboard on the iPhone so then .. what is the equivalent?

By the way I already have the *Text Size* slider set to absolute smallest in the general *Settings| Text Size*

Comment: I don’t use Chrome for a number of reasons, but wouldn’t the standard “Pinch-to-Zoom” work for *magnification* (equivalent to Cmd-+). It works in Firefox and Edge

Comment: i am not looking to _increase_ magnification (per title) but _decrease_ it

Comment: You reference zoom in your question and ask for it’s equivalent.  Cmd-plus and Cmd-minus is zoom

Comment: using finger/pinch does not work (had actually tried it: just momentarily gets smaller but does not incorporate new content/change layout). Saying zoom-_in_ is  a different animal than _out_ because there are many _accessibility_ features to help _only_ with the former.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling “Text Accessibility”

1. Type `chrome://flags` into a Chrome tab.
2. Search for "Enable text accessibility in web pages"
3. Select "Enable"

Force quit Chrome and restart.

Answer sourced from a [Google help](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9487841?hl=en) page about the same topic.

Comment: I am trying to make text/content _smaller_  not larger

Comment: Then that’s probably as small as it’s going to get.  iOS isn’t going to have features that the App doesn’t make available.